# Tensor product of two fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, commutative-algebra, tensor-products

Let $F, k'$ be two fields containing a given field $k$.  The book I'm reading (Borel, Linear Algebraic Groups) uses some facts about the structure of the tensor product $F \otimes_k k'$, for example the fact that every prime ideal is minimal.  Does anyone know a reference which explains some of these properties?

Comment: That "fact" is not true without some additional hypotheses.

Comment: Well alright, tell me where you got that information lol

Comment: I mean, it's clearly false if $F=k'=k(x)$.  If I'm not mistaken, it's true iff either $F$ or $k'$ is algebraic over $k$.  Sorry, I don't know of a reference though.

Comment: The Krull dimension of the tensor product is the minimum of the transcendence degrees of the two field extensions. This was first proved in the Errata of the last EGA IV, p. 349, and independently (ten years later) by Sharp (The dimension of the tensor product of two field extensions, Bull. London 9 (1977)) and in the same year (also independently) by a Russian mathematician (I do not remember the reference). Of course, the algebraic case should be known much before, but I neither know a reference.